# Wp Rest Api Custom Endpoint for page subpages

Tags: rest-api

I'm tring to add a custom endpoint for a page subpages.

Parent Page ID = 151

```
function list_subpages( $data ) {
   $subpages = get_pages( array(
       'child_of' => $data['151'],
   ) );

   if ( empty( $subpages ) ) {
       return null;
   }

   return $subpages;
}
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    $version = '2';
    $namespace = 'wp/v' . $version;
    $base = 'subpagelist';
    register_rest_route($namespace, '/' . $base, array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => array($this, 'list_subpages'),
    ));
});
```

Getting status 500 error..

How can I fix it?

Comment: This may be not related to `500 Error` but I wonder how `$data['151']` giving you parent ID ?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure. I have changed codes like this (https://gist.github.com/sakarya/62cb0e2cabf2602775ad), but still, getting same error.

Comment: I just tested the above code and do not see any 500 error. Perhaps you should check for server logs. 500 error hard to debug without server logs!

Comment: error message is: {"code":"rest_invalid_handler","message":"G\u00fczergah i\u015fleyicisi ge\u00e7ersiz","data":{"status":500}}

Comment: from the provided code it looks like your class instance `$this`  is not configured... **edit** try as callback just the string `'list_subpages'`

Comment: yes @iantsch. it works now, but shows only the last content. how can I list all content?

Comment: modify your `list_subpages ()` function to your needs. it might probably just be a configuration mistake in your [get_pages](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works..

```
function list_subpages() {

   $data = array();
   $request = array();

   $id = 151;
   $subpages = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $id, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) );

   if ( empty( $subpages ) ) {
       return null;
   }

   foreach ($subpages as $p) {
       $data['id'] = $p->ID;
       $data['title'] = $p->post_title;
       $data['img'] = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($p->ID) );

       $request[] = $data;
   }

   return new WP_REST_Response($request, 200);
}
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
   $namespace = 'wp/v2';
   $base = 'hizmetler';
   register_rest_route($namespace, '/' . $base, array(
       'methods' => 'GET',
       'callback' => 'list_subpages',
   ));
});
```

Comment: Lovely. Almost a copy-paste solution for me. Thank you. You could potentially comment on the code a bit for the programmers who learn.